# How to add manually control while editing gridview? ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I search on google but i can't find the solution.e.Rows or e.row not working in my visual studio 2010.How can i get this property.I want that when i click on "edit" button then gridview have different columsn and one column name is "Data Type" then this column fill with "dropdownlist" and i select value from drop down list.My dropdown control id is "dropdownlist1" .How can i do it?.Here is my code "gridview edit" event code:

```
protected void GridView2_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
  DataTable t = (DataTable)Session["MyDataTable"];
  GridView2.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
  DropDownList ddlName =
                (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("dropdownlist1"); // HERE IS ERROR AT "Row" 
  ddlName.DataTextField = "Data Type";
  ddlName.DataValueField = "Data Type";
  GridView2.DataSource = t;
  GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

Here is my aspx code :

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" 
        AutoGenerateEditButton="True" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" 
        BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" 
        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" onrowcancelingedit="GridView2_RowCancelingEdit" 
        onrowdeleting="GridView2_RowDeleting" onrowediting="GridView2_RowEditing" 
        onrowupdating="GridView2_RowUpdating" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        Width="92px">
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
    </asp:GridView>

</div>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="137px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="20px" 
    onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="140px">
    <asp:ListItem>int</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Varchar</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:CheckBox ID="Null" runat="server" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="Primary" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Insert" 
    style="margin-left: 59px" Width="56px" />
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Height="33px" style="margin-left: 76px" 
    Text="Create Table" Width="94px" />
```

Is I'm on the right way?or how can i do it?And also tell me how can i update the gridview row.I insert values in gridview manually.There is no database connectivity etc.Thanks

Comment: on which Event of GridView You are trying `e.Row`??

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the row with the index:

```
GridViewRow row = GridView2.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
```

**UPDATE**

You can put the DropDownList in a TemplateField of the GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ...>
    ...
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DataTypeValue")) %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTypeName" runat="server" ... />
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    ...
</asp:GridView>
```

(I showed an optional `ItemTemplate` in case you want to display the selected data type)

Then you can retrieve the DropDownList in your event handler:

```
GridViewRow row = GridView2.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
DropDownList ddlTypeName = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlTypeName");
...
```

Comment: But i want that when i click on "edit" button then gridview have column which have name "Data Type" then this column fill with "dropdownlist" and i select value from drop down list.my dropdown control id is "dropdownlist1" .How can i do it?

Comment: You can show your markup and add that new question to the one that you already asked. If the DropDownList is in a `TemplateField` of the GridView, you should be able to retrieve it with `FindControl`, like you do in your code sample (after replacing `ddlName` with `dropdownlist1`, if that is the name of your control).

Comment: I don't want to add new column or template field,I want that my "Data Type" column fill with "dropdownlist" when i press edit.

Comment: Then, your "Data type" column should be a TemplateField. I don't see a better way to do it.

Comment: But i don't want to add extra column,if i add template field then extra column will be added,

Comment: You can set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`(like in your code sample), and create all the columns in markup (probably `BoundField` for most of them). The "Data Type" column would be a TemplateField. It would be the only column for that field.

Comment: You mean to say i add values using footer template?

Comment: You can have a look at this code example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479353.aspx